# Serious error when trying to draw a circle on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, fatal-error, drawrect

I'm trying to draw a circle, so I've got the following method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGRect leadingCircle = CGRectInset(rect, 2, 2);;
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:leadingCircle];
    CGContextRef aRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(aRef, 20, 20);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(aRef, 0.1, 0.05, 0.9, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(aRef, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextRestoreGState(aRef); 
}
```

then I call it from viewDidLoad:

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);
[self drawRect:myRect];
```

but nothing is drawn and the following message shows in the console:

> CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you've put drawRect: in a UIViewController.  Instead, it should be in a UIView and you do not call drawRect: directly -- the system will call it automatically.

Comment: And don't call `CGContextRestoreGState` unless you have first called `CGContextSaveGState`.

Answer (score -1):

change your code with this.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, 
      [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: OP is in a view controller, not a view.

Comment: Incorrect. As I said, OP is in a view controller, not in a view.